# C++, open a file knowing path and file name (beginner)

Tags: c++

This is my very first experiment with C++ and I'm in general new to programming languages, so sorry if I use inappropriate language.

I am basically trying to write a C++ code in order to directly open a file, **knowing the path of the file** and the **file name**. I tried in different ways but there's obviously something (I guess extremely easy) I am missing.

I started with this example I found on internet (that's perfectly working, entering the file path and file name when prompted in the console):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string path;
    string file;
    cout << "Please enter the path (location) of the file: ";
    cin >> path; // gets user input for location
    cout << "Please enter the file name (with extension): ";
    cin >> file; // gets file name

    string openString = "start " + path + "\\" + file; // the string for the command

    system(openString.c_str()); // sends the command and converts from type string to constant char

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I then edited the code in this way, accordingly to my needs:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string path;
    string file;

    path = "C:\\test ";
    file = "test1.pdf ";

    string openString = "start " + path + "\\" + file; // the string for the command

    system(openString.c_str()); // sends the command and converts from type string to constant char

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The issue here is that my code, only opens the C:\test\ drive but not the file "test1.pdf".

Any hint?

Thank you very much, Stefano

Comment: Is the space after `test` supposed to be there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cris, I'm not sure, I thought a space was need but it's really my first try. I removed the space but it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Try hardcoding the entire path in `openString` rather than trying to put pieces of the path together. If that doesn't work, open a command prompt and execute the same command in it. Perhaps you have no default handler for pdf files? Your program works fine for me once I remove the trailing spaces from both the path and filename.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I tried what you suggested and also this worked, thanks.

Comment: Think about what happens in your code: You create the string `"start_C:\test_\test1.pdf_"` (with spaces where I wrote underscores). Try executing that on the command prompt, see what happens. Do you have a file `"C:\test\ test1.pdf "`? I would guess it needs to be `"C:\test\test1.pdf"` (without spaces)!

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, you're absolutely right, I only thought that for some reason, coding in C++, required a space before the closing double-quote. However what you wrote makes perfectly sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to fix this problem change `C:\\test`  to `C:\\test\\` that way you can access the file.

Comment: There's already a backslash being added in the code. Your suggestion adds another.

Comment: @RetiredNinja fixed.

Comment: @aragornii it worked with the `C:\\test\\` right. If it did this is because you are now referring to the next folder rather than a space which usually screws up accessing files.

Comment: Thanks @Jake, actually what you suggested (before editing your message) worked! I changed `C:\\test` with `C:\\test\\` and also removed the "\\" from the "string Openstring" line.

Comment: In general, even on Windows, you should use _forward slash_ instead: `C:/test/myfile.txt`. This always works.